# Variable Defining Issue Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, undefined

I'm trying to randomize a string depending on how many players their are and assign each player their job/role. In the Chrome Console I am getting the error,
"Uncaught ReferranceError: al is not defined." I dont get what the issue is, the variable is defined before using it(defined in first button, used in second).
I have an alert in the document that proves the variable is defined, and when pressing the button it says in the parameters al.
HTML:

```
    <input maxlength="1" id="input"> <button id="gp" onclick="gp()">Start!</button>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <button id="DJ" onclick="DJ(al, rl);BlankDisplay(al, rl)">Display Your Job!</button>
    <br/>
    <span id="DS">1) Input Amount Of Players. 2)Click 'Display Your Job!'</span>
```

Javascript:

```
function gp(){
    players = document.getElementById("input").value;
    if(isNaN(players)){
        alert(players.toUpperCase() + "'s Players? Please Fix"); 
        return;
    }
    if(players === " "){
        alert("Please Define How Many People Are Playing!");
        return;
    }
    if(players === ""){
        alert("Please Define How Many People Are Playing!");
        return;
    }
    if(players < 4){
        alert("Sorry, You Need Atleast 4 Players To Play!");
        return;
    }
    SA(players)
}
function SA(players){
    var positions = ["Murderer", "Judge", "Innocent", "Innocent"]; //Pre-set positions
    if(players == 5){
        positions.push("Co-Judge");
    }else if(players == 6){
        positions.push("Innocent", "Co-Judge"); 
    }else if(players == 7){
        positions.push("Murderer-2!", "Innocent", "Co-Judge");
    }
    Randomize(players, positions)
}
function shuffle(o){
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = Math.floor(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
}
function Randomize(players, positions){
    var rl = shuffle(positions);
    var al = positions.length;
    confirm("You Have: " + al + " Players, Correct?");
    alert(al + ". " + rl);
}
function DJ(al, rl){
    var counter = 0;
    var bd = 0;
    for(var c = 0; c < al + 1; c++){
        if(counter == 0){
            document.getElementById("DS").innerHTML(rl[c]);
            document.getElementById("BJ").innerHTML("Click To Clear!");
            bd = 1;
        }
    }
}
function BlankDisplay(al, rl){
    if(bd == 1){
        document.getElementById("Click The Button Above To See Your Job!");   
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like an scope issue. you are trying to pass `al` & `rl` on the button with id `DJ` but the `al` & `rl` don't live in this scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two function, DJ and BlankDisplay (nevermind the use of caps) that both take arguments of al and rl, but second function doesn't make use of al, or rl. Then in this code: `<button id="DJ" onclick="DJ(al, rl)` you pass in the variables al and rl into the function call for DJ, but unless you've defined the var al and rl as properties on the window/global scope, then those are undefined.

I'm guessing you're confused about the distinction between a variable and and an argument. So I'd start there.

Comment: So do I have to define that variable like: "var al; & var rl;" before the first function? Is their any website you know that goes in-depth because I have lots of issues that have to do with undefined.

Comment: on click, that button will run the javascript code: `DJ(al, rl)` but what are al and rl?

Comment: to make it clearer to you, rename the arguments for function DJ to not be al, rl. Is it clear to you that the two varialbles being passed in can be differently named than the arguments that the function expects?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `al` & `rl` from your DJ parameters. They live in a global scope and should have access to `al` & `rl` WITHOUT the need of passing it via the `DJ` button's `onclick`.

- Update button `DJ` like so: `<button id="DJ" onclick="DJ(); BlankDisplay();">Display Your Job!</button>`.
- Add `al` and `rl` before everything in your JS like so: `var al, rl;`.
- Omit `var` in your Randomize. So this: `var rl = shuffle(positions); var al = positions.length;` should become this: `rl = shuffle(positions); al = positions.length;`.
- Change this line `function DJ(al, rl){` to this `function DJ(){`.
- Change this line `function BlankDisplay(al, rl){` to this `function BlankDisplay(){`.

This should do.